# How to validate text from file and check it?

Tags: node.js

Hello my fellow coders..
OK so let me start with a list to show you everything.

1. There is a service called *dubtrack.fm* where people can play songs in a queue where they have to wait.
2. I am using their API. And made it so every song the song title gets saved in a .txt file.
3. I was wondering if someone does `!history` in the chat if it will read the .txt file and check if the song name is in there...

   4. I am also using nodejs which is what the APIis currently using. 
      This is everything in order what I need help with,
      I thank you for reading this and taking your time to help me!

Comment: please clarify where is the problem ?

Comment: I did clarify sir @KhurramIjaz